# Can I install subversion client in Centos 5 for offline installation?

Tags: svn, centos5

My Centos Version is :

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
Release:        5.6
Codename:       Final
```

I want to install subversion client to centos offline, How can I achieve that ?

So far I've download some file for subversion such as :

```
subversion-1.8.9.tar.gz
sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
```

But, I don't know what to do, to full install package for subversion client only. Anything else that I need to offline installation ?
For complete use of that subversion client..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to install a subversion client on a machine that can't fetch packages directly using yum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download rpm package and install it offline.

Download rpm packages for Centos 5 & Install via command line using

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/mod_dav_svn-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/subversion-devel-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/subversion-javahl-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/subversion-perl-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/subversion-ruby-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

wget -c http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm

Comment: My Centos `$basearch` is `i386`, so what file on [that](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/subversion/) repo that I must download it ? it's redirect to [http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/](http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/extras/RPMS/)

Comment: Download rpm files released on 25-Nov-2010.  There are six rpm files.

Comment: can you edit your answer and include the list six rpm file you're point at ? :)